# I have a Wordpress driven site, my contact form 7 plugin is adding a ton of whitespace to the bottom of the form and I'm not sure why

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7

For some odd reason, my contact form 7 plugin, which I have embedded into the front-page.php file using the following code:

```
<div id="contact" class="pad-section">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Contact Us</h1>
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="180" title="Request A Quote"]'); ?>
  </div><!-- container -->
</div><!-- contact -->
```

is adding a ton of whitespace below the submit button.  Upon examining the code, I see that the culprit is

```
<img class="ajax-loader" src="http://foxpile.net/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Sending ..." style="visibility: hidden;">
```

I'm not sure how to stop this, or why this is happening.  I've tried to disable other plugins but nothing seems to work.  I've tried the form on a separate page and it seems to work fine (you can click the Start Your Project link at the top and see for yourself)

Stylesheet contact code

```
/* Contact */
#contact { }

#contact .container {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem I think:

```
media="all"
.pad-section img {
   width: 100%;
}
```

I disabled that in the DOM using inspect element, and it fixed the extra padding, so I would set that value to "none" or just delete ".pad-section img" class altogether.

```
media="all"
.pad-section img {
   width: none;
}
```

Or remove the class.  Give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the CSS code for the contact form? It's
probably something in the CSS.
I would guess to much padding some where.
See if you can find something like: `padding: ...px;` or `padding-left: ...px;` (something like that). Then try to make the number lower. Ex. if it's 300px, try to make it 50px and see what happends!

(When i type ..., for ...px i mean a value + px ex 13px)